# EC2 + ssh: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I opened a new EC2 instance for the first time on AWS. However I can't SSH to it because it gives me `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Perhaps it's because I haven't done anything with the `new.pem` file?? What am I supposed to do with my `new.pem` file?

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:Downloads emai$ ssh -v -i new.pem 12.12.12.123
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 12.12.12.123 [12.12.12.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file new.pem type -1
debug1: identity file new.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 18:0a:02:e7:75:25:7e:78:27:a2:c8:ec:0a:e0:c0:a8
debug1: Host '12.12.12.123' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/emai/.ssh/known_hosts:77
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: new.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is a completely fresh server, with a newly generated private key. Let me know if you need any more info.

==UPDATE==

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:Downloads emai$ ssh -i new.pem emai@54.88.57.225
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You need to specify a username for the connection using `user@IP` or `-l  user` syntax

Comment: By user do you mean my IAM user? I updated the question on the bottom

Comment: No, the username for logging into the new EC2 instance. Amazon default is `ec2-user` as Harry suggested

Comment: NICE IT WORKED!! so now do I create users directly from the console? I thought the IAM user group + user I just created would appear (although I did make it after I made the instance)?

Comment: depends if you need more shell users and what is in your AMI.

Comment: Worth taking a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ssh -i new.pem ec2-user@your-ip assuming its an Amazon Linux distro.

Comment: Hey Harry I updated my question trying your method.. didn't work

Comment: @Edmund try using `ec2-user`, not *your* username you login to your computer with but instead the username the person who created the Amazon AMImage used which is often `ec2-user`

Comment: Your root key (new.pem) references the ec2-user. So you need to use ssh -i new.pem ec2-user@<your_instance_ip>